# Proof in set theory with infinite indices

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Prove that

$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\{ \bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty} E_n\}=\{ x: x \in E_n$ for an infinite number of indices $n \}$

Can't solve that, just trying to begin with contradiction: $x \in E_n$ for the **finite** number of indices $n$. Then can't proceed.

Comment: Welcome. You haven’t provided much of a thought process here, or shown your difficulties, so it is difficult to write you a *helpful* answer. I and many others could easily give you “the” answer, but that probably wouldn’t address your concerns appropriately (and could be seen as an unfair effort ratio). Please edit your question

Comment: Hint: a property of integers $\varphi(x)$ holds *infinitely often* iff for every $k$ there’s an $n\gt k$ such that $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Let $F_k=\cup_{n\ge k}E_n.$ Let $B(x)=\{n: x\in E_n\}$..... (1). If $k_0\in \Bbb N$ and $B(x)\subseteq \{n:n<k_0\}$ then $x\not\in F_{k_0}$..... (2). If $B(x)$ is infinite then for $any$ $ k\in \Bbb N$ there exists $k'\ge k$ such that $x\in E_{k'},$ implying $x\in F_k.$ ... BTW the set $\cap_{k\in\Bbb N}F_k$ is called $\lim\sup_nE_n.$